# TypeError: unbound method setSize() must be called with Page instance as first argument (got classobj instance instead)

Tags: python, class, init

When I run the code provided below, I get the following error:

TypeError: unbound method setSize() must be called with Page instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

> In my main, I call a class called Page. The variable pageSize is an integer.

```
from Page import Page as Page
def main():
   #other code....

   Page.setSize(pageSize)
```

> This is my class of Page:

```
class Page:
    def __init__(self, frame):
    self.frameId = frame
    self.pageId = -1
    self.timeEvicted = 0
    self.timeLoaded = 0
    self.ifLoaded = False
    self.ownerProcess = 0
    self.referencedWords = []

def initalize(owner, pgId, refdWord, ifLoad):
    self.ownerProcess = owner
    self.pageId = pgId
    addRefdWord(refdWord)
    self.ifLoaded = ifLoad

def setSize(s):
    self.size = s
```

Answer (score 1):

Every instance method (one that has access to `self`) must have `self` be the first parameter:

```
def initalize(self, owner, pgId, refdWord, ifLoad):
              ^^^^^

...

def setSize(self, s):
            ^^^^^
    self.size = s
```

Otherwise, `self` isn't defined in the function body. Similarly, `Page.setSize(pageSize)` will not work because you do not have an instance of your class. You need to create one before calling an instance method:

```
page = Page()
page.setSize(pageSize)
```

Now, `page.size == pageSize`.

Answer (score 0):

you first have to instantiate an object of your class and call the function on the object, to use `self`
You must define `setSize` as a class method to use it on the class

```
class Page:
    @classmethod
    def setSize(cls,s):
        self.size = s
        //cls refers to the class itself
```

Comment: i keep getting the same error, even after using @classmethod

Comment: Oops, yes try that @MarkJ.

Comment: Do i need to import anything to use that?

Comment: Sorry, last one @MarkJ

Comment: @MarkJ, no you do not need to import anything that is a matter of indentation of the code

Comment: TypeError: setSize() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: I'm only passing in one argument though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159861/discussion-between-user10089632-and-markj).